# Storyboard -JPEG

Tags: ios, xcode

I love the XCode storyboard I want to export it to jpeg or PDF or something that i can email to others people who don't have XCode program. How to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Off topic, Stack Overflow is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storyboards in Xcode are XML files and not actual images and cannot be exported as images. Instead, you can press <kbd>⌘ ⇧ 4</kbd> to go into screen shot mode and take a picture that way. It will automatically be saved to your desktop.

Comment: It's really disappointing that Apple has not built this feature into XCode yet. I've seen at least 5 other posts on SO with the same question.

Imagine what we could do if we could see every scene and segue all at once. I know it would make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

XCode doesn't have an exporting function built in for story boards, but to achieve what you want you could just double click the storyboard you want, go to fullscreen and take a screenshot.